# Converting numeric values of Longitude and Latitude to Spatial Data

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sp

I have a data frame `EuropeanCities` of latitude and longitude

```
Latitude Longitude
52.00529    4.173965
51.87938    6.268500
43.36661    -8.406812
```

Currently these values are of a numeric class however I need to set them to spatial coordinates for spatial data

How do I go about converting the class of these values using the `sp`function?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SpatialPoints` from the `sp` package..

```
    mydf <- structure(list(Latitude = c(52.00529, 51.87938, 43.36661), Longitude = c(4.173965, 
6.2685, -8.406812)), .Names = c("Latitude", "Longitude"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
    library(sp)
    SpatialPoints(mydf)
    # SpatialPoints:
    #      Latitude Longitude
    # [1,] 52.00529  4.173965
    # [2,] 51.87938  6.268500
    # [3,] 43.36661 -8.406812
    # Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
```

(You can supply your own proj string and so on; see `?SpatialPoints`).